# To set the background image in wrapper class

Tags: html, css

I write these code and made 2 grid using bootstrap.Now i want to the backgound image in the wrapper class.I tried it but i din't get success. Any idea about this?

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url(http://www.steamatic.com/images/footer-pattern-grey.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class=" flex">
      <div class="media-left"> <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i></div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4>Resenditial Services</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="para">Steamatic knows that the health and safety of your family is your first concern. Our restoration and cleaning services are all about providing you with the healthiest indoor environment possible.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class=" flex">
      <div class="media-left"> <i class="fa fa-building fa-3x"></i></div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4>Commercial Services</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="para">We've been providing commercial clients money-saving and asset-protecting services for nearly five decades. Steamatic's full range of restoration and cleaning services means we have your business covered.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the image in my background but i want to get full width image what i do?
U can show the image i upload

Comment: I don't see a problem. I tested your code and the background image appears fine.

Comment: it works! it appears fine :D

Comment: The code works fine. can you share a link or check your console?

Comment: It should be a browser issue for you, try emptying your browser's caches and see if it helps

Comment: The code works fine.. no problem!

Comment: I voted to close this question since it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: in my site these code isn't working

Comment: @SamsonMaben maybe you have tested in jsfiddle, in the code its ```col-md-6``` which will work in jsfiddle because it shows result in small viewport

Comment: @AwsmeSandy Yeah I tried in fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation of bootstrap, the cols are always wrapped in a `row` , if you want to wrap it in your own `.wrapper` class, then add

```
.wrapper{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or you can try `float: left;` to .wrapper , its your choice

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto;` to your .wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `overflow: hidden` to your `.wrapper` class parent element of the two floating elements inside of it. So that if you add background image on your `.wrapper` it will show. Because, bootstrap grid classes are using float.